# Using GPIO mode in SIM908

Tags: pic, gpio, sim900

I'm working on a SIM908 module using GPIO mode (my rx pin contact is lost when soldering).
I have interfaced it with a PIC16F73 and while using GPIO mode I'm not getting any response. I have included an LCD to print the response. Is there any AT command or pins I should enable on SIM908 to activate GPIO mode or is it because there should be a delay between writing and reading on the ports?

I have included the code:

```
   char x[20], y[20];
   TRISB = 0x00;
   PORTB = 'A';
   PORTB = 'T';
   PORTB = '\r';
   TRISB = 0xff;
   x[0] =  PORTB;

   LCD_Print_String(2,1,x[0]);

    if (x[0] == 'O')
    {
        LCD_Print_String(1,1,"done");
    }
    else if(x[0] == 'E')
    {
        LCD_Print_String(1,1,"error");
    }

    while(1);
```

sim908 datasheet:http://www.synes.co.th/nicupload/20111109110456.pdf

Comment: On most GSM modules the GPIO lines are for interfacing with other devices not sending / receiving data. How do you have them connected, that module looks like it only has two GPIO lines anyway?

Comment: SIM 908 has 6 GPIO pins for communication(its datasheet says they can be used for communication). I have connected them to my Port B pins. In the code I have asked to print whatever response i get from SIM 908 and two times it showed 'or' maybe 'or' of 'error'. So is it about the delay between sending and receiving commands

Comment: It might be worth editing youur question and adding a link to the datasheet and point out where it says that, I see I was looking at an old one. I can't see how it could possibly work though with 6 lines, any ASCII letter for example has a value >= 64 and needs a 7th bit.

Comment: i have included the datasheet of sim 908 . .the pin diagram shows nly 6 pins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the datasheet I can't see any mention of being able to use the GPIO for sending AT commands and data. I suspect where you've read about using the GPIO for communications they're referring to say attaching a switch which could be viewed as communicating the switch's state to the module. Apart from that there are a number of holes in just trying to connect six GPIO lines and attempting to send ASCII data:

1. From your example the character "A" in ASCII has a decimal value of 65 or 1000001 in binary. That is 7 bits long so you'll be dropping part of the character, the same will apply for any ASCII value of 64 or higher which includes all uppercase and lowercase letters.
2. Parallel data transfer schemes typically need additional lines apart from just data lines. For example you might have something like `R/W` to indicate if data is being read or written, `RDY` to make sure the device is ready for a transfer and `ACK` to indicate the data has been transferred.

There is mention that the SPI and I<sup>2</sup>C interfaces can be used for AT commands and communications but only if you have custom firmware. That sounds like something you would have to pay for them to develop rather than something available off the shelf.

I think with the broken `RXD` line you might be out of luck unless you're able to repair it. You might have some luck with a scalpel to carefully scrape off some of the solder mask and soldering on a piece of wire wrap wire or perhaps a single strand of wire from some multi-strand wire, assuming there is some amount of track left before it gets to the RF shield.

Comment: other modes of transmission requires updating firmware which requires rx pin. thank u for ur time

Comment: It looks like the firmware upgrade ueses the debug pins, so no harm asking them if they have some firmware available, but wouldn't hold my breath too much on them providing it at no cost.

Comment: but i read that to update the firmware  a software is needed. where can i find this software for firmware update. and thanks for your help

Comment: I couldn't see it but because you'll need to ask about the custom firmware for it to work you could ask them that at the same time. Some companies don't make them public because some users will update to the newest version when they don't have a specific problem and cause them more support calls if something goes wrong.

Comment: i will try to contact them and send them a mail